# Using generics as variable types in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

**I wish to change the following code so I could pass a parameter of type T or Component in this function such that it can be used in the type arguments**. This would be used in place of `ButtonManager` in the following code, Is this possible? Could I use `generics` to accomplish this? I wish to do this so I can reuse this method for a variety of Component types, vice having to make a method per component type.

```
private GameObject[] FindInActiveObjectsByType()
    {
        List<GameObject> validTransforms = new List<GameObject>();
        ButtonManager[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<ButtonManager>() as ButtonManager[];
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
            {
                objs[i].gameObject.GetComponent<ButtonManager>().ConfigureInteractives();
                validTransforms.Add(objs[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
        return validTransforms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: isn't this anyway the case for `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<T>()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using the generic overload [`Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) which always returns `T[]`

In order to make the rest (e.g. `GetComponent`) work you only have to make sure that `T` is always of type `Component` so you would do

```
public GameObject[] YourMethod<T>() where T : Component
{
    List<GameObject> validTransforms = new List<GameObject>();
    T[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            //objs[i].gameObject.GetComponent<T>().ConfigureInteractives();
            validTransforms.Add(objs[i].gameObject);
        }
    }
    return validTransforms.ToArray();
}
```

---

**Note** however that `ConfigureInteractives()` seems to be specificly related to your `ButtonManager` and will throw an exception since it is not part of `Component`.

So in case you need this for other stuff inheriting from `ButtonManager` then simply exchange the `Component` with `ButtonManager` in

```
public void YourMethod<T>() where T : ButtonManager
```

---

> How could I check the passed in Type

There are multiple ways. You could e.g. check the exact passed type using

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(ButtonManager)) (objs[i].gameObject.GetComponent<T>() as ButtonManager).ConfigureInteractives();
```

but then you could also simply g back to using

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(ButtonManager)) objs[i].gameObject.GetComponent<ButtonManager>().ConfigureInteractives();
```

or you could use maybe [`typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(ButtonManager))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof) for also matching inherited types.

Comment: Amazing, this really helped me understand generics. Now I can call the method with YourMethod<TheComponentTypeToPass>()! Generics are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do the following:

```
public void YourFunction<T>() where T : Component
{
    T component = gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
}
```